# WordPress wp_ajax not working as expected

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

Have been looked at the WP ajax documentation for hours now and still can't
figure this out

All of the code is in on single page. Trying to update some options via ajax
and it just is not working. The response is saying its successful, but the
current_form option is not being updated. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
add_action('wp_ajax_AWNT_save', 'AWNT_save_data');
function AWNT_save_data() {
update_option('current_form', 'foo');
}
echo get_option('current_form');
?>



<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#save').click(function() { 
        var data = {
            action: 'AWNT_save',
            form_name : $('#form_name').val(),
customC: $('#customC').is(":checked"),
no_throttle: $('#no_throttle').is(":checked"),
form_code : $('#form_code').val()};

        jQuery.post( ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            alert('Response: ' + response);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You're submitting this data to the same page?

Answer (score 0):

To make ajax working you need add two action hooks, one already you have and another one is required to work when user is not logged in and it's `wp_ajax_nopriv_AWNT_save`, this will make ajax working without requiring to log in and finally add `die()` at last of the function to stop executing further, otherwise it'll always return `0` and `echo` should be used inside the function.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_AWNT_save', 'AWNT_save_data');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_AWNT_save', 'AWNT_save_data');
function AWNT_save_data() {
    update_option('current_form', 'foo');
    echo get_option('current_form'); 
    die(); // this should be here
}
```

Also you should remove your `javascript` from the `single.php` and keep it in a separate `js` file, for example inside your theme's root folder create a sub folder `js` or what ever you want and keep the file in that folder and name it for example, `my_single_ajax.js` and paste the javascript code in that file as follows

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { // my_single_ajax.js file
    $('#save').click(function() {
        var data = {
            action: 'AWNT_save',
            // more...
        };

        jQuery.post( ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            alert('Response: ' + response);
        });
    });
});
```

in your `functions.php` file add an action `hook` as follows

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
function my_scripts_method() {
    if(is_single())
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my_single_ajax', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/js/my_single_ajax.js'); // assumed your sub folder name is 'js' and file name is 'my_single_ajax.js'
}
```

This will enqueue the script (my_single_ajax.js) only when it's the `single.php`, that's it.

Comment: This is for a plugin options page, which is why I didn't use nopriv as only people with admin rights will be using it. I intended to place the javascript in a separate file, but only once everything was up and running. I don't think that should have any overall effect on how the page works though. Additionally, I'm getting ajax from ajaxurl, in the administration section. But I do have the enqueue script as well.

Comment: So what you get from the response ?